# Minimum hardware and software requirements to install Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios

What is the minimum hardware and software specification to install XCODE 8.0 in a MAC PC or Laptop?

Comment: Absolutely no reason for downvotes on a valid question that Apple doesn't answer. People's real life experience is necessary here.

Answer (score 5):

Software requirement: **Mac OS X version 10.10 (or later)**

Hardware Requirement: (Least/Enough )

- 1.4 GHz of Intel Based CPU (Mac)
- 4GB of RAM

Higher the configuration, better the performance.
If you are going to use swift as development language then 16GB of RAM if preferred with 2.5GHz of Processor.